# iOS: Transitioning between views with animated subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

What is the "right" way to transition between views while moving a view during the transition?

Basically, I want something that's like opening the Photos.app and tapping a photo: from a thumbnail it expands to be full screen as the app transition from the collection view to the detail view.

Preferably, this should be done with **Auto Layout**, but I have no idea how...

Thanks!

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

**NO**, I do not think it can be done using **Auto Layout**. You can have a view controller for displaying a full screen image, let us say `PhotoViewController`. Now you can use **presentViewController** to display your `PhotoViewController` modally, using following piece of code:

**`Note: Code Mentioned below assumes you are using iOS 7 or later sdk.`**

```
 UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
 PhotoViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PhotosView"];
 vc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 vc.transitioningDelegate = self;
 vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;
 [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Now in your `animateTransition` method you can have something like:

```
 -(void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {
    NSIndexPath *selected = self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems[0];
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:selected];

    UIView *container = transitionContext.containerView;

    UIViewController *fromVC = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController *toVC = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
    UIView *fromView = fromVC.view;
    UIView *toView = toVC.view;

    CGRect beginFrame = [container convertRect:cell.bounds fromView:cell];

    // Would be safer to use container bounds here
    CGRect endFrame = [transitionContext initialFrameForViewController:fromVC];

    // NOTE: Remove this line for full screen goodness
    endFrame = CGRectInset(endFrame, 60.0, 60.0);

    if (toVC.isBeingPresented) {
        toView.frame = beginFrame;
        [container addSubview:toView];
        cell.hidden = YES;
    }
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0
         usingSpringWithDamping:500 initialSpringVelocity:15
                        options:0 animations:^{
                            if (toVC.isBeingPresented) {
                                toView.frame = endFrame;
                            } else {
                                fromView.frame = beginFrame;
                                cell.hidden = NO;
                                [fromView removeFromSuperview];
                            }
                        }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [transitionContext completeTransition: YES];
                     }];
    }
```

Hope this helps, feel free to revert back if you have some queries.